# Apache Solr Query Building

Tags: solr

I am a newbie to Apache Solr. I am trying to figure out the tokenizer, filter, and query parameters for the following query, but haven't been able to figure out if it's possible yet (still reading through all the documentation):

I have two fields - `title` and `description`. We want to do a search where:
 1. Matches from `title` have more relevance than from `description`.
 2. Complete word matches take precedence over all others (for query `kit`, `kit` takes precedence over `kitchen`).
 3. An index entry that begins with the query field takes preference over one that just contains the field (for query `goo`, `good` takes precedence over `Magoo`).

Is this even possible? If so, how do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Weighting between fields isn't an issue that tokenizers or filters are concerned with - their job is to take some input text, split it into tokens (tokenizers) and then run it through a sequence of processing steps (filters).

The [edismax and dismax query parsers](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/the-extended-dismax-query-parser.html) have a parameter named `qf` that allows you to give a list of fields that should be queried, and give a separate weight for each one - allowing you to tune exactly how much weight to give to each field. `qf=title^5 description` would weigh a hit in the field `title` five times higher than a field in `description` - all things else being identical (but they usually aren't identical, since you're not indexing the same content into both fields).

And that's the reason why scoring isn't an exact science, so if you want to have some sort of relevancy score used (i.e. different words hit will give different scores), you'll have to tweak these weights to fit the rank you're looking for. Appending `debugQuery=true` to a query is very helpful when you're tweaking scoring, since it'll show you exactly how much each term is contributing to the end score for a document.

Your first criteria, `title` vs `description` is solved by having a TextField with a StandardTokenizer and a lowercasing filter (and depending on what you're looking for, optionally stemming, synonyms, etc.).

You'll also (probably) want a lowercasefilter in the examples given below, but I've omitted it to keep the examples compact.

Your second case is solved by having a second field type that has an [EdgeNGramFilter](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/filter-descriptions.html#FilterDescriptions-EdgeN-GramFilter), and then having two new fields - `title_edge` and `description_edge` that uses this field type.

Both this and the NGramFilter example below uses the `type="index"` attribute, since it usually only makes sense to expand ngrams when indexing. Otherwise any two words starting with (or for NGram Filter, containing) identical letters would give a match.

```
<analyzer type="index">
  <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
  <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="2" maxGramSize="40" />
</analyzer>
<analyzer type="query">
  <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
</analyzer>
```

The third criteria is solved by having a third set of fields, `title_ngram` and `description_ngram` that has an NGramFilter in its sequence:

```
<analyzer type="index">
  <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
  <filter class="solr.NGramFilterFactory"/>
</analyzer>
<analyzer type="query">
  <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
</analyzer>
```

Be aware that an NGramFilter will result in *a lot* of tokens being generated, require more storage and making searches process more tokens when generating a match. This may or may not be relevant for your use case.

That being said, there's something to be said about matching inner terms in words - especially very short strings. They might give results where the user isn't able to understand why the document was matched, as it might be a small match (a single letter while typing a query) somewhere. Someone searching for just "c" to find something about the programming language, will get every hit that has a word that contains c (but if you've boosted your fields properly, the exact hit should be at the top, luckily).

Comment: Thank you Mats for the very helpful and detailed response!

Comment: `q=title:order1 || description:order1`
`qf=title^5`
But the document where `order1` is in the `description` field has a higher score (`0.94566005`) than the one where `order1` is in the `title` field (`0.9331132`). What's up with that?